# Simple HTML DOM how to access the elements at the top level only

Tags: php, html, dom

i'm stuck with the subj question. 
this is the sample code:

`include('./simple_html_dom.php');
$html = str_get_html("
<cols>
    <br>
    <col>
        content1
        <br>
        content1
    </col>
    <br>
    <col>
        <br>
        content2
        <br>
        content2
    </col>
    <br>
</cols>");`

foreach($html->find('cols br') as $br) {
    echo $br->outertext;
}


this gives me all the `<br>` tags inside the `<cols>` tag, but i need the `<br>`'s only on the top level.
`$html->find('cols > br')` doesnt work also(

**UPDATE**
resolve this :
`foreach($html->find('cols') as $cols_tag_content) {
    for($node = 0; $node < count($cols_tag_content->children()); $node++) {
        if($cols_tag_content->children($node)->tag == "br") {
            //doing whatever you want with br. i just remove it
            $cols_tag_content->children($node)->outertext = "";
        }
    }
}`

this works with `<br>` and `<br />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
foreach($html->find('cols') as $cols_tag_content) {
    for($node = 0; $node < count($cols_tag_content->children()); $node++) {
        if($cols_tag_content->children($node)->tag == "br") {
            //doing whatever you want with br. i just remove it
            $cols_tag_content->children($node)->outertext = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried 'cols>br'? I think the 'cols > br' *may* be throwing it off.

See http://www.w3schools.com/css/sel_element_gt.asp also for maybe more information.

I think jQuery allows for the spacing though.

**UPDATE**

I restructured your pseudo-html above to use divs with classes to the following:

```
<div class="cols">
    <br />
    <div class="col">
        content1
        <br />
        content1
    </div>
    <br />
    <div class="col">
        <br />
        content2
        <br />
        content2
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Executing the following jQuery script works now:

```
var brs= $('div.cols > br');
alert("Found "+brs.length+" brs");
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes, i've tried this, unfortunately it gives me all 6 `<br>`s too

Comment: ah! I see what you're saying, let me take another spin on this

Comment: why not changing your <br> to some <br /> and use something like SimpleXML ? :p

Comment: 1)i can't change my markup. 2)SimpleXML cannot resolve my problem in a global sense, so i need to use simple_html_dom. i resolve this, update the first post if someone has the same problem. thanks for your replies anyway :)